# How to implement `jwt` using express js in mvc pattern?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have gone through this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens). How can I implement this in mvc pattern?

This is my file structure

```
config
   |----mongo.js      //connection to mongoose
   |----routes.js     //all routes of all controllers
controllers
   |----controller.js //all controller files
models
   |----model.js      //all models nothing but schemas of different collections
package.json
server.js
```

How to implement jwt in the above pattern so that it can be applied to all routes. Please help me out.

Comment: You can check https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt

Comment: @MaheshSalaria, where are we doing signup, storing and verifying? And for every route do we need to give the secret key?